# How to set data from slot-scope to component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I'm new in Vuejs, I have some problems with `slot-scope`,

```
<template>
  <some-component>
    <div slot-scope="{someMethod, someData}">
      // the problem is i need someMethod in my current component, not in template
    </div>
  </some-component>
</template>


<script>
export default {
 created() {
   // i need to access someMethod and someData here
   this.someMethod();
 }
}
</script>
```

Is it possible?
What is the best practice way?

Comment: There's probably a better way to go about this. What does `someMethod` do?

Comment: something like initing form

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense with regards to the slots.  Does this fiddle answer your question?  https://jsfiddle.net/posva/uzd56xv2/

Answer (score 1):

You can send your component's method to your slot host, and then provide that in the returned slot scope.

```
<host :someMethod='someMethod'>
  <div slot='foo' slot-scope='{someMethod}'>{{someMethod()}}</div>
  </div>
</host>
```

Or send the entire component to the slot host, and have the host send it back.

```
<host :me='me'>
  <div slot='foo' slot-scope='{me}'>{{me.someMethod()}}</div>
  </div>
</host>

<script>
computed:{
  me(){ return this;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Inspired. Thanks you gave me an idea.